# Migrating multiple DbContexts in two different projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two seperate projects in the same solution. One is a windows sevice and the other is a ASP.Net application. The solution doesn't have a seperate data layer. The projects communicate to its own separate database. In the second project which is the web application when i try to do a Enable migration with the following command in the "Package Manager Console", I get an error.

The command:

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName ServicesMock.Data.MockContext - 
MigrationsDirectory:MockMigrations
```

The error refers to the first project and says that the context type "ServicesMock.Data.MockContext" was not found in the assembly "Assembly of the first project in my solution"

How can i sought this out so that the migration command can be pointed to the relevant project ?

I was referring to [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801628/Code-First-Migration-in-Multiple-DbContext) to create the commands.

I tried changing the startup project as well.

**Updated (added this section)**

Corrected the issue of not selecting the proper Default Project in the package manager console.

In the first Project (Windows service) the Application.config file contains the dbcontext for that project

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationDbContextConnection" connectionString="data source=abc;initial catalog=serviceDB;user id=;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

The purpose of the second project (Web Application) is to mock some External API references used in the first project. It doesn't have a application.config, instead a web.config.

It has its own DbContext. I have added the connection string in the web.config which is

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="MockContext" connectionString="Data Source=abc;Initial Catalog=mockDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

But now when I try to EF migrate the 2nd project(Web Application) , I get an error "No connection string named 'MockContext' could be found in the application config file." But the web application does not use a app.config file. Is it referring to the 1st project ?

Comment: And you changed your default project to the correct project within the Package Manager Console?

Comment: @user10728126 oh i didnt do that. Now i tried that. But I am getting a new error "No connection string named 'MockContext' could be found in the application config file.". But i have the connection string in the web.config of the project. Should I include it elsewhere ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mock your dbcontext and if so you shouldn't need a connection string. I can't really tell because you didn't post any code. Are you doing unit tests? Can you post them?

Comment: Now I'm confused. When you say "mock some External API references" are you setting up unit tests? If so, they shouldn't be in a web application, they should be done in a class library project using a mocking framework like moq. If you're just setting up some HTTP methods (GET, PUT, POST, etc..) to test API calls, then the web application makes sense, but you shouldn't be running migrations. Just add the models and the dbcontext manually to the web application from your other project. Migrations are used to initialize and update the db on the fly so as your models change, your db changes.